# Read and write data multiple times on a serial port with a single click

Tags: c#, serial-port

I need to read and write data to a serial port with a single click of a button.

A sensor board is attached to my PC, with a micro controller on it.

I have to do the following things with a single click:

- Send some data to the micro controller, like the sensor's register address
- Read the data the controller sends back
- Send the address of another sensor
- Read the data
- Etc

Afterwards, I have to do some calculation with the received data.

How can I send and read data multiple times with a single click of a button ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
            serialPort1.Open();
            serialPort1.Write("$g helloboard!"); // A message sending to micro controller. After that micro controller send back a message. 
        }

        string str;

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
            serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);

            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            str = enc.GetString(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to read and write port with in button1_Click .

Comment: As a first comment, it is incorrect to subscribe for serialPort1.DataReceived in the button click, as there will be new subscription for every button click and it will never get unsubscribed. You can subscribe for the event in the constructor.

Comment: From the above example I see that you send a command to the controller and receive the response for it. Alternatively you can combine all the commands using a delimiter like "command1;command2;command3" and write it to the controller. The controller should be able to receive this and get the commands after splitting the string using the delimiter. The it can execute the command one by one and send back the response.

Comment: You can use `Timer` to repeat same procedure. Other options is to run long running job (which opens com-port, write something, read, whatever) in `Thread`/`Task` or use `async/await` to be able to invoke the job directly from button click handler. An advice: put device communication into separate class (`IDisposable`), don't clatter logic by putting it inside the form.

Comment: @SureshKumarVeluswamy Then how can I read.Could you please explain little bit. I am new in C#

Comment: Every time you receive a response from the serial port, you receive it in serialPort1_DataReceived event handler. You can receive the data here decide what you want to do with that.

Comment: Hi! I have cleared up the question, so that it's more clear. Please take care to write clear and precise questions, so that we're able to answer you.

Comment: @Sinatr 
 
I have to clear one more thing. After sending $g helloboard! command how can i handle received data. I know received data will be store inside serialPort1_DataReceived event inside a string named as str.How can i access this string inside private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) .So that i can perform some calculations on it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @MuhammadUmairAkbar, here are keywords for you: 1) run code in parallel (so you can run a job from UI thread), 2) synchronization (so that you can wait for data to be received) 3) `async/await` (advanced technique to make usage very simple for user). You can't wait inside `button1_Click` event for data directly (unless you are using async/await), that would block UI thread and your program become unresponsive. The easiest would be to start timer, which will be used to check after some time if data are received (you will have to provide flag, which you set in `DataReceived`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple (and dirty) solution is to have something like this

```
    private bool data_received = true;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (data_received)
            {
                data_received = false;
                serialPort1.Write("$get register 42");
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

and in your Callback `serialPort1_DataReceived` add:

```
data_received = true;
```

This is just for testing purposes. It is far from a good solution, next task would be to do the working in a background thread, so your GUI doesnt get blocked, and of course to define a condition that breaks the while-loop.

Comment: I have to clear one more thing.  After sending $g helloboard! command how can i handle received data. I know received data will be store inside serialPort1_DataReceived event inside a string named as str.How can i access this string inside private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) .So that i can perform some calculations on it. Thanks in Advance.